# Rename Files in Directory Appending Three Digit Numbers and Spaces and Varying Extensions via Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, filenames, rename, macos

I have a list of files in a directory that display like this via an `ls` command:

```
01-Campout 2001.jpg
2-Campout 2001.png
Campout 2001 - 3 of 21.tiff
Campout 2001 - 4.pdf
```

I would like to know what bash command I could use to remove the current numbering and replace it with a naming convention that has a three-digit number count at the beginning while preserving the text afterward to include the space between Campout and 2001. This has a mix of .jpeg and .png files.

What I would like the end result to look like:

```
001-Campout 2001.jpg
002-Campout 2001.png
003-Campout 2001.tiff
004-Campout 2001.pdf
```

Thanks so much

Comment: @thanasisp Sorry, I edited my post to be more clear. The files read via 'ls' to read as the first block, but I would like to have a one-line bash command to get it to 'ls' like the second block.

Comment: So, do you want to actually **rename** the files or only change how `ls` displays them?

Comment: While you say that your filenames "have a sequential two-digit number", it seems that some files have not. Also more text (dash delimited always?) appeared after 2001. And more extensions, like tiff, not only "a mix of .jpeg and .png files". I guess you are okay if the answers are making some assumptions on these things.

Comment: @thanasisp The idea is to get all the files in my directory to have the same naming convection made up of three components `00#` (ascending number count)  `-`  `Campout 2001` while preserving the space between `Campout` and `2011` as well as the correct extensions. I am running MacOS so it plays nice with the spaces and looks nice in Apple Photos when browsing through my massive library.

Comment: @Quasimodo Yes, would like to read in each file in the `ls` order, then completely rename each file (before the extension), with the above final convention. Thank you for your patients with me.

Comment: At the risk of piling on — please clarify the rules for what you will have as input, what you want kept and what you want discarded.  Will ***every*** name contain `Campout 2001`?  Might there be titles like `2001 A Space Odyssey`, `Apollo 13` and `1776`?  Are the numbers to be removed always preceded by a **`-`**?  Would you want `The Taking of Pelham - 123` to be renamed to `The Taking of Pelham`? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
$ zmv -n '((<1-999>)-(*)|(*) - (<->) of <->(.*)|(*) - (<->)(.*))' '${(l[3][0])${:-$2$5$8}}-$3$4$6$7$9'
mv -- '01-Campout 2001.jpg' '001-Campout 2001.jpg'
mv -- '2-Campout 2001.png' '002-Campout 2001.png'
mv -- 'Campout 2001 - 3 of 21.tiff' '003-Campout 2001.tiff'
mv -- 'Campout 2001 - 4.pdf' '004-Campout 2001.pdf'
```

(remove `-n` (for dry-run) if happy).